# Find a negative cycle in a directed graph using Dijkstra?

Tags: graph

I have a directed graph G=(v,e) with a negative edge (u,v). All other edges are positive.

How can I find a negative cycle using Dijkstra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `(u,v)` from the graph. Find shortest path from `v` to `u` (with Dijkstra). If its total weight is less then `-w(u,v)`, then you have found negative cycle. Otherwise no such cycle exists.